# Yahoo! Messenger no longer recognizing Yahoo! ID

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-messenger

With Yahoo! Messenger open on my Macbook (OS X 10.8.2), I closed my laptop for a couple of hours. I have done this before without problem. However, last night, when I opened my laptop, Yahoo! Messenger had disconnected from the network and logged me out. With the network connection now re-established, I attempted to logon and use Yahoo! Messenger with the same account I had previously used, but no success. Either the login fails or the wheel just spins.

Also, I had saved this Yahoo! ID along with three others. The other two remain as options to select when logging in. However, the Yahoo! ID I was using when I closed the laptop is no longer available. I have to re-enter the Yahoo! ID and password now.

Comment: Does it work on Yahoo's website?

Comment: It works from Yahoo! Mail for that user.

Comment: And using it from Yahoo! Mail seems to have corrected the problem with the app. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging into Yahoo via the web, that might get it working, or at least let us know if it's an account issue or a messanger issue.